# string literal spanning multiple lines in C

Tags: c, syntax

I encountered the following type of string literal in an open source library, which I have not seen before. It turns out that `a` and `b` are the same. I'm confused why the syntax of `a` is correct? Does C preprocessor concatenate two strings automatically?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
const char a[] =
"123\r\n"
"123\r\n";

const char b[] = "123\r\n123\r\n";

printf(a);
printf(b);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [section 5.1.1.2.6 of the C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

So your assumption is correct.  Anyplace you see string literals consecutively, the compiler implicitly concatenates them.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. It's quite convenient in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Te declaration

```
const char a[] =
"123\r\n"
"123\r\n";
```

is equivalent to

```
const char a[] = "123\r\n123\r\n";
```